# gulp-useref is ignoring files if there are more than 25 files

Tags: gulp, gulp-useref

I'm using [generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) and have 27 html files compiled to the `.tmp` folder. I found only the first 25 html files will be process and pass to the `dist` folder during the gulp-useref task. Here's the `gulpfile.coffee`'s code, really need to know how to fix this, thanks.

```
gulp.task 'views', ->
  gulp.src [
      '!app/mixins/**/*.jade'
      '!app/layouts/**/*.jade'
      '!app/partials/**/*.jade'
      'app/**/*.jade'
    ], base: 'app'
    .pipe $.data (file) ->
      return JSON.parse fs.readFileSync '.tmp/data.json'
    .pipe $.jade
      pretty: true
      basedir: 'app/'
      compileDebug: true
    .on 'error', (err) ->
      $.notify
        title: 'Jade compile failed.',
        sound: 'Sosumi'
      .write err.message
    .pipe gulp.dest '.tmp'

gulp.task 'htmlProcess', ['views', 'styles', 'scripts', 'compass'], ->
  assets = $.useref.assets
    searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']

  gulp.src ['app/**/*.html', '.tmp/**/*.html']
    .pipe assets
    .pipe assets.restore()
    .pipe $.useref()
    .pipe gulp.dest 'dist'
```

Comment: Can you show us your original files?

Comment: I'm sorry I can not show you the files because it is a private project of my client. Here's the original [gulpfile.coffee](https://gist.github.com/judewang/efc57ce38cf31e202f94), I found if I remove one or two tasks which belong to `htmlProcess`, then it can compile all files without losing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a working test case to replicate this issue. I believe I have found a fix for this. Check out the most current version of the repo or wait for the next version to be published on npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref

Comment: What is the status of this issue? We are using 3.1.2 version and the problem still exists.

Comment: As far as I know, it's resolved. There are passing tests in the repo. If you could provide a failing test or a reduced test case, that would help.